# Selenium chromedriver returns empty data for canvas

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a selenium set up as:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)   
driver.get('file:///path_to_file')
```

When I execute the script:

```
data = driver.execute_script('return document.getElementsByClassName("runner-canvas")[1].getContext("2d").getImageData(0,0,600,150);')['data']`
```

Data is all zeros: `[0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0 ..., 0,0,0,0]`.

But when I take a screenshoot, at the same time, with:

`driver.save_screenshot(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), '.', 'screenshot.png'))`

I can see that the canvas is populated.

Canvas loads a game that doesn't start till the `SPACE` is pressed.
Function that is responsible for collecting the canvas data looks similar to this:

```
# Somewhere before the __get_data is called
self.document.send_keys(Keys.SPACE) # self.document is set to html document


def __get_data(self):
    while self.driver.execute_script("return Runner.instance_.started") == False:
        print('Waiting to start')
    # data is always empty at this stage
    data = self.driver.execute_script('return document.getElementsByClassName("runner-canvas")[1].getContext("2d").getImageData(0,0,600,150);')['data']
    rgba = np.array(data).reshape((90000, 4))
    b = a[:, 2]
    return a.reshape((150, 600))
```

When I run it I can see a lot of `'Waiting to start'` in a console, hence I don't think it is a timing issue as by the time `while` breaks everything should be drawn as the game already started.

Im on Mac running `ChromeDriver 2.46.628411`

Comment: Your headless flag might be interfering from noticing that your canvas doesnt fully load before your script grabs the data. Try it without the headless flag and try to figure out if you can use an explicit or implicit wait. Normally I use explicit WebdriverWait s and then figure out if I can tie my wait to an element showing up, and then replace it with an implicit wait.

Comment: @BoboDarph I forget to add `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` to the question, but I have it in the code. Updated the question. Running it without the headless mode is the same. I have updated the question with some more code.

Comment: So you run __get_data in a loop, right? Otherwise it would make no sense to see multiple instances of it. Try adding a wait after the SPACE is sent. Your Runner.instance_.started might return True, but the canvas might not still be populated.

Comment: I have added a `sleep(1)` after the `SPACE` been sent. Same problem. General idea is: Connect selenium, wait for a game to start, collect the canvas data. I can run the `__get_data` in a loop with `1s` intervals and I still get the empty `data` regardless for how long I wait. The canvas data returned by the `execute_script()` is always empty. But it shouldn't be.

Comment: Can you also add a small wait in your while loop, after the print? PS: you might want to look into using sikulix if Selenium keeps being stubborn. I've had success in using it to automate canvas tests that gave Selenium trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Thought so the image that you are trying to capture or get the data from it it's not loaded properly hence you having the empty data, do one thing find out how much time it's taking to load the image and add that much wait and after that get the data and screenshot

Let us know that if works or not..